How to log out of Synology SSO Server (OIDC)?
I use Synology SSO Server (OIDC). I used a python library to log in and it works perfectly, the url that is called to login looks like this:
https://<MY-NAS>/webman/sso/SSOOauth.cgi?response_type=code&client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>&scope=openid+email

The problem is that I do not know how to log out. I can't find any Logout URL as I know it from keycloak. Not in the Server's interface nor in .well-known/openid-configuration. And the only piece of documentation I found is this:
https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/Software/DeveloperGuide/Package/SSOServer/All/enu/Synology_SSO_API_Guide.pdf
But with the Javascript SDK, I can't even log in, I get an error:
Invalid SSO client application. Please go to Application List page and try to add the application again.
Also, the URL looks completely different:
https://<MY_NAS>//webman/sso/SSOOauth.cgi?scope=user_id&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>&inframe_id=babuiir5bxl&synossoJSSDK=true&app_id=<APP_ID>&state=08uqkyqxr1

Does anyone know how to log out?
Im a little frustrated because there is so little documentation. In the future, I plan to switch to keycloak anyway, but right now I don't want to copy all the users from Synology NAS into keycloak and I dont have LDAP to connect them.
